# Sampling with replacement, expected number of repeats

Tags: probability, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I have a bag containing $100$ unique balls. I sample from this bag, with replacement, $100$ times.

From [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1056540/45001) answer I can compute the *"expected number of duplicates",* or using the Binomial Theorem I can compute the probability that I will see any specific ball drawn twice, or $k$ times. However I can't figure out how to determine:

**How many times would I expect the most drawn ball to be drawn from the bag?**

I suspect it's something to do with the a sum of the binomial distribution, but as you can tell I'm no mathematician.

Comment: Here is a solution (under different formulation) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/146418/expectation-of-maximum-of-uniform-multinomial-distribution