# calculate expected collision count

Tags: probability

Let's say I have a uniformly distributed random number sequence whose values are in the range [1, **m**]. Each value has a chance of **p** = 1/**m** appearing. Take a sample of size **s** from that sequence. For a given value in the sample, let **n** be the number of duplicates in the rest of the sample. Let **c** be the count of numbers in the sample that have the same **n**.

For example:

- if **n** = 0, then **c** is the number of unique values in the sample.
- if **n** = 1, then **c** is the number of values that have one same value in the rest of the sample.

So for a given **n**, how to calculate the expected **c**?

Below are some simulated results.

for **m** = 65536, **s** = 1000

| n | c |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 978 |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 0 |

for **m** = 65536, **s** = 10,000

| n | c |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 8598 |
| 1 | 1284 |
| 2 | 114 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 0 |

for **m** = 65536, **s** = 100,000

| n | c |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 21806 |
| 1 | 33326 |
| 2 | 24915 |
| 3 | 13076 |
| 4 | 4865 |
| 5 | 1566 |
| 6 | 350 |
| 7 | 96 |
| 8 | 0 |

Comment: Questions: You don't explicitly say it, but when you say "in the range $[1,m]$" you mean *integers* in that range, right? When you say "take a sample of size $s$" you mean *with replacement*, right?

Comment: You say "For a given value in the sample, let $n$ be the number of duplicates in the rest of the sample." Let me see if I understand this. If our sample were $\{1,3,3,4,1,1,3\}$ then the associated sequence of $n$ values would be $2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2$? Or do we keep only one copy of the $n$ value for a given grouping of identical samples, in which case the set of $n$ values associated with the above sample would instead be $2, 2, 0$?

Comment: @JohnBarber The answers in turn are: right, right, and 2,2,2,0,2,2,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ denote the number of values in the sequence that take on value $i$, where $1 \leq i \leq m$, and let $Z_n$ the number of values in the sequence that are the duplicate of exactly $n$ other values.

What we're interested in computing is $\mathbb{E} Z_n$, where
$$ Z_n = \sum_{i=1}^m (n+1)\mathbb{1}\{X_i=n+1\}.$$

By linearity of expectation, this is
$$\mathbb{E}Z_n = \sum_{i=1}^m (n+1)P(X_i=n+1)=m(n+1)P(X_1=n+1).$$

Since $X_i\sim \text{Binom}(s,1/m)$, we have

$$P(X_1=n+1)=\binom{s}{n+1} \left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{s-n-1},$$

therefore
$$\mathbb{E}Z_n = (n+1)\binom{s}{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)^{s-n-1}.$$

For m = 65536, s = 100,000:

| n | c | $\mathbb{E}Z_n$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 21806 | 21743.1 |
| 1 | 33326 | 33177.5 |
| 2 | 24915 | 25312.3 |
| 3 | 13076 | 12874.3 |
| 4 | 4865 | 4911.1 |
| 5 | 1566 | 1498.7 |
| 6 | 350 | 381.1 |
| 7 | 96 | 83.1 |
| 8 | 0 | 15.8 |

Comment: Picked this one because it is way faster to calculate

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical content behind this question has already been answered here:
[Sampling with replacement - Expected number of duplicates, triplicates, ..., n-tuples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056540)

However, the phrasing is slightly different, so let me help translate. In this problem, we have a sequence of random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_s$, where each $X_i$ is uniformly distributed in $\{1,\ldots,m\}$, and we wish to compute the expected number of $X_i$'s which are unique ($n=0$), repeat exactly twice ($n=1$), and so on, for all $n$.

In the question I linked to above, the names of the variables are different but it is the same mathematical setup. The $m$ in our problem here, is the genome size in the other question. The $s$ in our problem here, is the sample size of the number of genes in the other question. Rephrasing the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry in this notation, the probability of seeing a particular value of $X_i$ exactly $k$ times is
$$
\binom{s}{k}\frac{(m-1)^{s-k}}{m^s}
$$
and therefore the expected number of indices $i$ such that the value $X_i$ appears exactly $k$ times is
$$
k\binom{s}{k}\frac{(m-1)^{s-k}}{m^{s-1}}.
$$
A value that appears exactly $k$ times corresponds to an $n$ value of $k-1$ in the notation of this question, so we obtain the formula:
$$
\mathbb E[c_n]=(n+1)\binom{s}{n+1}\frac{(m-1)^{s-n-1}}{m^{s-1}}
$$